# Solving a 2D partial differential equation from an old science paper

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

I am reading an atmospheric science paper (B. J. Hoskins, 1985) and stumble on a second-order partial differential equation that after some simplification roughly reads
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r} (\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial (rv)}{\partial r}) + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} &= \frac{\partial P}{\partial r} \\
\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial v}{\partial r} - \frac{v}{r^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} &= \frac{\partial P}{\partial r}
\end{align*}
where $v(r, t)$ is some function of $r$ and $t$. $P$ is a quantity that has a value of $1+\epsilon$ inside the circular region $r^2 + t^2 = C^2$, and and $1$ outside the circle, where $\epsilon$ is a very small number. The boundary conditions should be $v = 0$, when $r \to 0$ and $r \to \infty$. The solution given in the paper is
\begin{align*}
v &= \frac{1}{3} \epsilon r & r^2 + t^2 < C^2 \\
v &= \frac{1}{3} \epsilon r (\frac{C^2}{r^2 + t^2})^{3/2} & r^2 + t^2 > C^2
\end{align*}
The paper claims that this is a straight forward theoretical exercise, but I have no idea how to arrive at the given solution. I have tried Separation of Variables but I can at most deduce that $v \propto r$ inside the circular region. Laplace Transform and Fourier Transform seems futile. I have tried to use Duhamel's Principle but my answer is wrong. I am thinking if some transformations can be applied.  Can anyone give me some suggestions? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $P = 1$ everywhere outside and $1+\epsilon$ everywhere inside, then its derivative with respect to $r$ is $0$ everywhere except on the circle itself, where it is undefined. The inside and outside solutions would be the same except for a constant. Did you mean $\frac {\partial P}{\partial r}$ is $1$ or $1 + \epsilon$ instead?

Comment: I have checked the paper and it says it is $P$ is $1+\epsilon$ inside and $1$ outside, though I am not sure if the author makes a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way (although not perfect) to derive the solution in a reasonable way. First make a transformation $Q = v/r$ to make the equation simpler, leaving three terms in the Equation. Then, by observation, one solution for $Q$ is a constant. Another solution for $Q$ is motivated by the circular boundary. Let $z = r^2 + t^2$ and assume that the solution is solely a function of $z$. By Chain Rule, the equation can be transformed into an ordinary equation in $z$ and it is possible to get another solution $1/z^{3/2}$. Due to the physics, we know that $Q = \alpha$ inside the circle, and $Q = \beta/z^{3/2}$ outside the circle. Finally, we consider the difference in P across the interface. By integrating over a small neighborhood at the interface, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be determined.